# magento add custom dropdown like country and their stated

Tags: admin, attributes

i want to add custom ajax drop down with values depending on its parent dropdown. like when country us is selected all states of us gets populated.

can i use that same login to create custom ajax mapping between two attributes ,

any way i can do this via module ??.

or use any built in feature of magento ?...please help

Answer (score 1):

So Magento has this built in feature in the admin section for general selector fields and you can also extend the region one to work in the front end with other select fields.

Have a look at the JS `SelectUpdater` in `js/mage/adminhtml/form.js` and `RegionUpdater` in `js/varien/form.js`. You should be able to use either of these with the select values in a JSON format.